# How can this be a string and not an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

[I´ve edited this whole post in order to get the whole script printed. I´ve posted a similar shorter version because I thought it could be easier because of the spanish... but of course... it wouldn´t...]

I have this form:

```
<b>3. Selecciona una opción</b><br>
<input type ="checkbox" name="servicios[]" value="uno">Un sólo servicio<br>
<input type ="checkbox" name="servicios[]" value="dos">Dos servicios<br>
<input type ="checkbox" name="servicios[]" value="tres">Tres o más<br>
```

And to get what the users selected I use:

```
$servicios = $_POST['servicios'];
   if(isset($servicios)){
      foreach ($servicios as $servicio) {
         echo $x."<br>";
         }
   }
```

Now, I have a database, and with a switch, I get the database equivalent of the element the user selected:

```
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,$query)
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
   while($datosdelabase=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
      if(isset($servicios)){
         foreach ($servicios as $servicio) {
         switch ($servicio) {
            case 'uno':
               $servicios=$datosdelabase['uno'];
               break;
            case 'dos':
               $servicios=$datosdelabase['dos'];
               break;
            case 'tres':
               $servicios=$datosdelabase['tres'];
               break;
            }             
            echo "Servicios:".$servicio.": ".$servicios."<br>";
         }
}
...
```

Inside the database, I´ve got each column with integer values.

That way if the user selects ie. uno. I get "Un sólo servicio" with $servicio and 1 with $servicios (because that´s what I´ve got from the database.

Now when I try to get the type, I get a string and not an array? Why is that?

```
echo gettype($servicios); // string

var_dump($servicios); // returns: string(2) "Two"
```

Comment: What is `$s`? How did you create it?

Comment: I believe it is: `$s = $_POST['s']`

Comment: Yes, it´s $s=$_POST['s'];. I´ve just updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: With the same code I get `array` in the type. Are you sure you are not checking the type of `$x`?

Comment: what is `var_dump($s)` ?

Comment: After testing (not just "I think that...") it really returns an array, either being one option selected or more.

Comment: Haven´t thought on that, I´ve updated the question: string(2) "Two"

Comment: what happens if he checks more than one checkbox?

Comment: I've just tried your code and I get `array` as a return for `gettype($s)` for any variation of chosen checkboxes

Comment: There is something else in you code your are not showing us... Are you doing the gettype outside of the foreach loop?

Comment: If I check more than one option, the result is the same. string(2) "Two"

Comment: yes! That´s it! I´m doing it outside the for loop! Let me see if doing it inside...

Comment: Ermm.. That's where you should be doing it. What do you mean That's it!

Comment: Well... I tought it could be it... it results the same string... even inside the for loop.

Comment: I´ll edit the post and add the complete version of the script...

Comment: I´ve added the complete version of the script. It´s in spanish (that´s why I thought in adapting it in order to get better understood. Clearly a mistake, sorry about that. Now it´s complete (and a little bit more complicated than the abridged version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are setting $servicios here:

```
$servicios=$datosdelabase['uno'];
```

or:

```
$servicios=$datosdelabase['dos'];
```

etc...

EDITED TO REMOVE ERRONEOUS STAEMENT:

You are doing `echo gettype($servicios);` which you set in the `case`,  which is a single string from the database

EDIT: This is the code to change:

```
foreach ($servicios as $servicio) {
     switch ($servicio) {
        case 'uno':
           $servicios=$datosdelabase['uno']; <--- CHANGE THIS to $servicios_2=$datosdelabase['uno'];
           break;
        case 'dos':
           $servicios=$datosdelabase['dos']; <--- CHANGE THIS to $servicios_2=$datosdelabase['dos'];
           break;
        case 'tres':
           $servicios=$datosdelabase['tres']; <--- CHANGE THIS to $servicios_2=$datosdelabase['tres'];
           break;
        }             
        echo "Servicios:".$servicio.": ".$servicios."<br>";
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But what should I do to get an array? I thought I´ve got one with name="servicios[]", and it was still an array because I´ve used foreach and worked...

Comment: I mean, how to get an array *again*

Comment: Not set the variable `$servicios` to a string. Just change the name of the variable in the 3 `CASE` statements.

Comment: Yes but WITHIN the foreach you are setting it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Because lines like this overwrite the value of $servicios

```
switch ($servicio) {
   case 'uno':
      $servicios=$datosdelabase['uno'];
      ...
      $servicios=$datosdelabase['dos'];
      ....
      $servicios=$datosdelabase['tres'];
```

What you should do is to use another variable to get the value of those from $datosdelabase. You should not use $servicios since that's the array you are traversing.

You can try this.

```
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,$query)
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
   while($datosdelabase=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
      if(isset($servicios)){
         foreach ($servicios as $servicio) {
         switch ($servicio) {
            case 'uno':
               $serviciosVal=$datosdelabase['uno'];
               break;
            case 'dos':
               $serviciosVal=$datosdelabase['dos'];
               break;
            case 'tres':
               $serviciosVal=$datosdelabase['tres'];
               break;
            }             
            echo "Servicios:".$servicio.": ".$serviciosVal."<br>";
         }
}
...
```

Where I've just used $serviciosVal instead of $servicios inside the case.